# Can i see temperature measurements for MLX90614 without using serial monitor?

Tags: arduino, output, arduino-c++, temperature, measurement

Im using arduino UNO with MLX90614 and when i upload it, it seems to run properly but once i open the serial monitor to see the results, the measurements taken from the time i upload till the serial monitor is opened is displayed. but after that, it just throws out a bunch of characters.

I tried to open it immediately after uploading the code but it will just show the characters.

[here's what is shown on the serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDU1A.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4pS9.png)

nvm I fixed it!

Comment: Issue might be with UTF-8 output. Check the reported issues like that https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/4231 for possible workarounds.

Comment: @ÖöTiib tried alr, still doesnt work zz but thanks!!

Comment: Can we see the section of the code?

Comment: @GuilhermeRocha i edited and added it to my post!

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen with non-strings printing out the serial monitor. Casting them to strings displays them correctly.

With something like this:

```
 float t = 0.0;
 Serial.println(String(t));
```

Comment: how do i do that? im new to C++